# C++11 regex end-of-line doesn't match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I can't get the $ (dollar-sign) to work as documented in C++11 regular expressions. This is with ECMAScript syntax (the default).

Example (regex.cc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    if ( std::regex_search("one\ntwo", std::regex{"one$"}) ) {
        std::cout << "Should match, doesn't." << std::endl;
    }

    if ( std::regex_search("one\ntwo", std::regex{"two$"}
                         , std::regex_constants::match_not_eol) ) {
        std::cout << "Shouldn't match, does." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:
    Should match, doesn't.

Actual output:
    Shouldn't match, does.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/:

> `$` - End of line - Either it is the end of the target sequence, or precedes a line terminator.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/:

> `match_not_eol` - Not End-Of-Line - The last character is not considered an end of line (`"$"` does not match).

Tested with Clang 3.3 and 3.4 on FreeBSD 10:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o regex regex.cc && ./regex
```

What am I missing?

Comment: by the way, cppreference is a little more detailed w.r.t.  C++ regex grammar: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled on [LWG issue 2343](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2343)

To quote,

> If Multiline is true, $ matches just before LineTerminator.
>
> If Multiline is false, $ does not match just before LineTerminator.

[,,,]

> Multiline of the existing implementations are as follows:
>
> Multiline=false:
>
> libstdc++ r206594
>
> libc++ r199174
>
> Multiline=true:
>
> Visual Studio Express 2013
>
> boost 1.55

Note: using the current SVN version of `libc++`, your first test IS actually matched, so looks like this LWG issue is going to be resolved in Multiline's favor

The second issue (`match_not_eol` ignored) looks like a fairly straightforward implementation bug. Boost.regex doesn't match that test case.